# XCode 4, Incompatible types in initialization

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

What is wrong with this code?

```
-(float) getRotatingAngle : (CGPoint)firstPoint secondPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint
{
   float dx = firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x;
   float dy = firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y;
   float angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(dy, dx));
   return angle;
}
```

An when i try to call it like this:

```
float ang = [self getRotatingAngle:projectile.position secondPoint:projectile.position];
```

I get the error from the title.
I am using cocos2d (COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00010001).

The code is inside a `ccTouchesEnded` handler in a `CCLayerColor`.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
projectile is a `CCSprite`

EDIT: the compiler error is (like in the title) `Incompatible types in initialization. TheLayer may not respond to '-getRotatingAngle:secondPoint'`)

HINT: That's my code copy-pasted from a cocos2d project, where it worked. Just that the project was cocos2d V2. (?)

Comment: do you have better luck if you use "`CGFloat`" and not `float`?

Comment: @Michael, nope, still the same.

Comment: Better show us how projectile.position is declared. Also, is getRotatingAngle:secondPoint declared before you try invoking it?

Comment: No, that was it but I figured it out at the same time as you did. Thanks. Don't know what to accept as an answer :S?

Comment: Give them all an up vote at least. Nobody added an actual 'answer', only comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add private method definitions to the top of your .m file, like this:

```
@interface SomeClass ()  // Note the empty parens here

-(float) getRotatingAngle : (CGPoint)firstPoint secondPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint;

@end
```

This lets you organize your methods later in the .m in whatever order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.
I just moved the method above the first call.
Then it worked. Extremely noobish.